# How can I use a Func<T, bool> as a parameter in a method that queries data from a SQLite database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have this code:

```
var ListToBeDeleted = db2.Table<Deck>().Where(x => x.Id == App.DeckId).ToList();
```

What I would like to do is to create a generic function that can be used for this case and others  using a Func<T, bool>.  I already have this but I am not sure how I can modify it.

```
    public List<T> RunQuery<T>(??) where T : new()
    {
        List<T> data = db2.Query<T>(s);
        return data;
    }
```

so that I can call it like this:

```
var ListToBeDeleted = db2.QueryWithWhere<Card>( <where clause here> );
```

Is there anyone that can give me some advice on how I could add in a where clause like this into the generic?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. Have you considered inspecting the `db2.Query<T>(s)` method signature, and looking at the type of the `s` parameter?

Answer (score 4):

The `Where` method takes an `Expression` parameter, so you would pass an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`:

```c#
public List<T> RunQuery<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) where T : new()
{
    var data = db2.Table<T>().Where(filter).ToList();
    return data;
}

// To use it
var ListToBeDeleted = db2.RunQuery<Card>(c => c.Id == App.DeckId);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use reflection to get hold of the property from the Entity and write something like this,

**Solution 1**

```
string property = "Id";
var ListToBeDeleted = db.Query<Card>(i=>i.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(val,null).Equals(id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Why would you mark it negative. This also solves the problem correctly and completely. You can use reflection, you can also use regular expression to parse the where clause and pass it dynamically to run the query.

Comment: @Alan2 wants to be able to dynamically pass an expression to the `Where` method, and that's easily done by passing an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. Reflection can be expensive, and if it's anything like Entity Framework, an exception will be thrown because the db provider doesn't know how to translate the reflection methods to SQL.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Entity framework, it has every thing to do with sql query only, sir, please remove your downvote, i found this answer for the user by searching in StackOverflow, this question itself is probably duplicate.

Comment: The question definitely has to do with Entity Framework, look at the tags. And again, even if your answer would work, it is not at all what the OP is asking.

Comment: The where clause is still generic in my solution, it uses reflection to find out the property name and can execute it there. For a more complex expression the solution which has been marked as answer would still not work Sir! He might have to create a RegEx Engine and pass the expression from the engine first and then execute it via Expression or by directly passing it to the property (which would be found from reflection) to the where clause.